# How to synchronously read data from Azure DocumentDb collection inside a server-side trigger?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to implement a trigger on an Azure DocumentDb collection, which is supposed to auto-increment a version of a document, which is being inserted. The trigger is created as a pre-trigger. 
The challenge I am facing is that collection class doesn't seem to provide a synchronous API for querying data. My plan for the trigger was to query existing documents, get the top version, increment, and assign the +1 value to the document, which is being inserted into the collection. But since the result of the query is only available asynchronously, by that time my trigger is completed and the document is inserted unmodified.
How can I await the query result?
Here is how my current trigger looks like:

```
// TRIGGER Auto increment version
    function autoIncrementVersion() {
      var collection = getContext().getCollection();
      var request = getContext().getRequest();
      var docToCreate = request.getBody();

      // Reject documents that do not have a name property by throwing an exception.
      if (!docToCreate.Version) {
        throw new Error('Document must include a "Version" property.');
      }

      var lastVersion;

      var filter = "SELECT TOP 1 d.Version FROM CovenantsDocuments d ORDER BY d.Version DESC";

      var result = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), filter, {},
                function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
                    if (err) throw new Error("Error: " + err.message);
                    if (documents.length != 1 || !documents[0]) {
                      lastVersion = 0;
                    } else {
lastVersion  = documents[0];
}
                   //By the time we reach this line, our trigger has already completed?
                    docToCreate.Version = lastVersion + 1;
                });
      if (!result) throw "Unable to read last version of the document";

    }
```

**UPDATE:** The issue was with the way I was submitting request. Looks like triggers are not fired by default, their names need to be explicitly provided as an argument to the request. 
In my case the trigger wasn't firing until I changed the client code to this:

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions
{
    PreTriggerInclude = new[] { "autoIncrementVersion"}
};
client.CreateDocumentAsync(url, document, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

It will automatically wait until all pending async operations either complete, fail, or time out before returning. What you have is close. The only thing that I can see is missing is that you never call `request.setBody(docToCreate)` after you alter `docToCreate`.

That said, I'm not 100% certain that this approach is safe. All operations inside of a trigger, sproc, or UDF are atomic, but I'm not sure that the combination of a pre-trigger plus a write operation is atomic. The risk is that two simultaneous writes will both run and complete the trigger part which would give them a same .Version. You would probably have to ask the DocumentDB Product Managers to confirm this. They hang out here so they may respond here.

If you find that it's not atomic, then you can move everything (read to find latest version and write) into a stored procedure (sproc).

You might also consider creating a single document whose `id` you hard code to something like 'LAST_VERSION' to hold the last used version. That means that every write will result in a read + two writes (one for the document and one to update this document), but it may be more efficient than your query + one write approach. You could do all of this in one sproc or you could use a pre-trigger (to fetch the 'LAST_VERSION' + write operation + post-trigger (to update the 'LAST_VERSION' document) depending upon what the Product Managers say about atomicity.

One more caution about your current approach... Make sure the precision of the index on the Version field is set to -1 (Maximum precision).

Comment: Larry, thanks so much, your answer sounds like a solution, I will try request.setBody() tomorrow, this must be the reason why version is not updated by my trigger.

Comment: Also, will research the atomicity aspect. And will make sure the precision of Version field is right.
One detail from your answer is not clear to me though - the bit about throwing if documents.length > 1. This is my first experiment with DocumentDb query syntax, so I am curios, doesn't TOP 1 keyword guarantee that I can't get more than 1 record back? Thanks again!

Comment: You are right about not needing the throw with TOP. I was thinking that it would confirm that no two documents have the same version but it won't do that. I edited that out.

Comment: Turns out, setBody() call doesn't make a difference in my case. The real issue was with the way I submitted request.

Comment: I have a question. We know that stored procedures are ACID atomic, but are they synchronous? Is there some sort of semaphore that will queue the calls to stored procedures? I'm asking because I wanted to add some sprocs to update some items, but even if atomic I'm afraid if several instances of the same sprocs execute at the same time one will succeed but others may fail if they try to update the item after the first instance did it. Are sprocs synchronous? Are they put in a queue?

Comment: They are not synchronous. They work off of a state marker and will either pass or fail (and rollback) depending upon whether or not there have been any conflicting state changes since the marker was set.